# Laravel Validator mime-types except certain types

Tags: php, laravel-5, mime-types

In my web application, I am allowing user to upload files and the application stores the file in Aws s3. I am using laravel 5.0 and want to validate file types using Validator class. I know the rule

```
mimes:jpeg,bmp,png
```

But My problem is I want to allow all files EXCEPT 'php,html,js'.

Is there any rule for It? or any custom function.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can only whitelist in the mimes validation, there is no blacklist function.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own (reusable) custom validator.
eg for Laravel 5.3 see:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.